# Ruin theory in R but i keep facing an error. Why?

Tags: r, coding-style

I'm applying theory to a scenario for a compound stochastic process. This is my code:

```
lab  <- 0.027
u    <- 10400
sims <- 3000
i    <- 370000
ruinvector <- rep(0, sims)
for (Z in 1:sims) {
  i <- 370000; time <- 0
  Wt <- vector(); sumWt <- vector(); Y <- vector(); sumY <- vector(); Ut <- vector()
  while (time<8766) {
    Wt[i] <- rpois(1 , lab); sumWt[i] <- cumsum(Wt)[i]; Y[i] <- 
    rgamma(1,81,0.018); sumY[i] <-
    cumsum(Y)[i]
    Ut[i] <- u - sumWt[i] + sumY[i]
    if (Ut[i] < 0) { ruinvector[Z] <- 1 }
    if (Ut[i] < 0) { break }
    time = time + Wt[i]
    i <- i +1 
  }
}
sum(ruinvector)/sims
```

This is done in R. With different values this works perfectly fine. However, with the values i need i get the following error:

```
Error in if (Ut[i] < 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
> sum(ruinvector)/sims
[1] 0
```

Any ideas on what this means and how to fix it will be great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't deface your own posts. You waste the work of the person that took the effort to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Step through your first iteration:

```
i <- 370000
...
Wt <- vector(); sumWt <- vector();
Wt[i] <- rpois(1 , lab)
sumWt[i] <- cumsum(Wt)[i];
```

So Wt will be a vector 370,000 elements long, and with the last element as `rpois(1,lab)`.  All preceding elements will be NA, and therefore the cumsum will also be NA.

And therefore, 'Ut[i] <- u - sumWt[i] + sumY[i]' will also be NA.  Your code fails because you can't call if on a logical test on an NA.